# Detecting 1st connection after register in grails

Tags: grails

In my grails application I want to know when it is the first login after a user successfully register.
I'm using the spring security core plugin.
What is the best way to perform this ?

Comment: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-configure-Spring-Security-redirect-url-after-login-td3235600.html

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're automatically logging the user in after registering, or know that the user will manually login right after a registration, you'll probably have to persist something like "lastLoginDate" with each user. Then just check if that value is empty (which is their first time logging in), otherwise just update the login date each time they login.

You can put this code in one of the events that is fired after a successful login.

**UPDATED based on comments**

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // fired after successful authentication
   // and AFTER user info provided to SpringSecurityService

   // to get currentUser, you can use the following
   def springSecurityService = appCtx.getBean("springSecurityService")
   def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
   ...
}


or

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   // fired after successful authentication
   // and BEFORE user info provided to SpringSecurityService
   // (e.g. springSecurityService.currentUser == null)
}
```

More info can be found on the [SpringSecurity documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/7%20Events.html) under events.

Comment: is it possible to use a service in config.groovy, so i can call springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you can inject springSecurityService - note that springSecurityService will not have currentUser for the user in onAuthenticationSuccessEvent. You will need to use onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent instead.

Comment: i tried to put this in my config.groovy but it doesnt work , when i login the code of the two method is not exécuted

Comment: just curious, but what happens when you log out, then back in. Does the event fire the second time you log in?

Comment: i tried to log out , then back in , and the event is never fired

Comment: did you also add grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true in Config.groovy per documentation, and restart grails just to make sure. it's working for me.

Comment: oops , i checked again today, i found out that i was editing the config.groovy of an other projet -_- , onAuthenticationSuccessEvent is now working for me , but still cant get the current user